# Deleted flag on Sunsolve patch description

Tags: solaris, patch-management

I have  question about the Sunsolve patch description. In the filelist of the files belonging to a patch, some files are marked as `(deleted)`. What does this mean? Is the file going to be deleted or just excluded from this revision of the patch?

For example in the [Samba Patch Description](http://sunsolve.sun.com/search/document.do?assetkey=1-21-119757-17-1) (not sure if a account is needed to browse this link), the file `/etc/rc3.d/S90samba` is marked as `(deleted)`. After installing the patch this file was missing and Samba was not started. That made me curious since a patch should not do something like that. Also the Patch notes don't have any information about that.

Maybe somebody has an idea. Thanks for your help.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"(deleted)" does indeed tell the patch is deleting affected files which are either no more used or replaced by something else.

In that particular case, the rc start script has been obsoleted by a Solaris 10 SMF service fixing bug 6310561.